# excel vba don't change automatically the value that I put

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create some tables in excel using vba. The data comes from a CSV file and while I am creating it I get a weird problem. There are some values that are for example "5 a", this is automatically converted into "5:00 AM" but this values have nothing to do with the time.

So I just want to put "5 a". I cannot find the way to put it in the right format.

Comment: Please paste your code here, we're not psychic.

Comment: either format the cell as Text **before** you write the data, or prepend the data with a single quote **'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending a single quote will prevent Excel from auto-formatting data:

```
CSVData = "5 a"
Range("A1") = CSVData
Range("A2") = "'" & CSVData
```

**Output**

[image]